# How to efficiently close the channel?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm trying to do some stuff:

```
type Feed struct {
    title, descr, link string
    published          time.Time
}
func main() {
    ar := make([]Feed, 0)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        f: = new(Feed)
        // do some stuff with feed
        ar = append(ar, *f)
    }

    ch := make(chan Feed, 3)

    for _, i := range ar {
        go process(i, ch)
    }

    r :=0
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Println(i)
        r++
        if r == 3 {
            close(ch)
        }
    }
}
func process(i Feed, ch chan Feed) {
 // do some stuff
 ch <- i
}
```

It seems that `ar` is unnecessary, but if it would be removed, last range would be forever. What i'm doing wrong?

Another question is - is that way of working with Go routines the right way?

Comment: This specific example could easily be done with a `sync.WaitGroup` without needing any channels. Channels are often used in provider-consumer type applications where you have one or more routines creating tasks, and one or more routines executing the tasks. So my question for clarification is this: does your code creating the `Feed`s take enough time for it to make sense to goroutines for both creation and consumption of the `Feed`s? Does the "do some stuff with Feed" actually take any time?

Comment: @RayfenWindspear thanks for reply, yes "do some stuff with Feed" can take many time, so i'm trying to get results from processing feeds asap, i don't want wait until all go routines would be finished

Comment: please paste the code you removed ar.

Comment: @mattn i don't have working example without `ar`, it's a problem, but i guess same code without `ar` is possible

Comment: @inJakuzi Yes, I said I want to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example producer-consumer type. I only use the `WaitGroup` here so that the main goroutine wouldn't exit instantly. Theoretically your application could either wait, or do some other interesting stuff in the mean time.

Note that you could also use a buffered channel using `c := make(chan(*Feed, n))` where `n` is the number you want buffered. Just be aware that in a typical producer-consumer scenario, there is sometimes a lot of resources allocated per job. So depending on that you could buffer just a few, or all of them if you wanted.

Without a buffered channel, it acts as a sync between the goroutines. Producers block at `c <-` waiting for a consumer's `<- c` to hand off to, so only one of each routine execute these lines at a time.

**EDIT** I added a pause before printing "started" to make the output less synchronized. It previously always output:

```
created
started
created
started
...
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FmWqegr-CR

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Feed struct {
    title, descr, link string
    published          time.Time
}

func CreateFeed() *Feed {
    r := rand.Int() % 500
    time.Sleep(1000 + time.Duration(r)*time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("Feed created")
    return &Feed{
        published: time.Now(),
    }
}

func UseFeed(f *Feed) {
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("Feed started")
    time.Sleep(1600 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("Feed consumed: %s\n", f.published)
}

func main() {
    numFeeds := 10

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(10)

    c := make(chan (*Feed))
    for i := 0; i < numFeeds; i++ {
        go func() { c <- CreateFeed() }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < numFeeds; i++ {
        go func() {
            f := <-c
            UseFeed(f)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

I'm hoping this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Looks like what i actually need, thanks.
One more question: is sync.WaitGroup main thing when using goroutines, i saw many examples with goroutines and WG together, but in golangtour there is no information about WG

Comment: @inJakuzi In my opinion, it's not really the right way and is kind of a cheater way to do this. Don't get me wrong, it definitely has its uses, but it kind of wastes the time of the main routine. I did it here to push my answer out more quickly, so I apologize for that. What I would normally do instead (given the assumption that the main routine continues on to use the results), would be to have the second loop insert into a results channel that the main thread would pull from. That way it could start as soon as one was done instead of `wg.Wait()`ing for the entire set of results.

Comment: There are a lot of subtle things to remember when dealing with concurrency, but the biggest one is obviously (and yet not so obvious sometimes) that want to be waiting a little as possible. Hence my aversion to `wg.Wait()`.