# How to understand and practice in concurrency with Go?

Tags: go, concurrency

I am learning Go, and one of most powerful features is concurrency. I wrote PHP scripts before, they executed line-by-line, that's why it is difficult for me to understand channels and goroutines.

Is there are any website or any other resources (books, articles, etc.) where I can see a task that can be processed concurrently, so I can practice in concurrency with Go? It would be great, if at the end I can see the solution with comments and explanations why we do it this way and why this solution is better then others.

Just for example, here is the task that confuses me and I don't know how to approach: i need to make kinda parser, that receive start point (e.g.: http://example.com), and start navigating whole website (example.com/about, example.com/best-hotels/, etc.), and took some text parts from the each page (e.g., by selector, like `h1.title` and `p.description`) and then, after all website crawled, I receive a slice of parsed content.
I know how to make requests, how to get information using selector, but I don't know how to organize communication between all the goroutines.

Thank you for any information and links. Hope this would help others with the same problem in future.

Comment: Because fetching webpages is `io` based, goroutines are perfect for this. It's not a perfect match to your question, but it could very well be adapted to your application. See this question I just answered an hour ago. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847571/1276480

Comment: And if you haven't already, do the https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1 .

Comment: First of all, think about the problem: from your brief description, I see no reason there should be communication between all the goroutines. All you need is to spawn each routine with an initial state (a page to scrape), and have it pass back whatever data you're scraping to one collector routine, via a channel. They shouldn't need to talk to one another.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear thank you. As i understand, producer will write a response or a document to channel (buffered) and the consumer will read the channel, on recieve it will parse the document and get the required data? It this data must be append() to result slice, or must be passed via channel to another function that appending? I did already the tour, but the examples there are so trivial, so when i need to do something more difficult, i dont know how to approach. It feels like a have lack of concurrency patterns.

Comment: @V.Korovin that is the basic idea, though you have to keep in mind that structures such as `slice`s and `map`s are not safe to write concurrently. This is usually where the channels come into play, to prevent race conditions. In the example I gave you, you could have another channel used by the consumer and the main routine to collect and use/store/whatever the results (instead of the `WaitGroup`).

Comment: BTW, `slice`s and `map`s can be **read** concurrently, but not written. Writes must use locks if multiple routines are writing. The exception being if you knew exactly how many work items to allocate in a `slice`, you could `s := make([]*Result, 10)` and write to it specifically **by index, not with** `append`.

Answer (score 1):

so there are [lots](https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#1) of [resources](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) [online](https://medium.com/code-zen/concurrency-in-go-5fcba11acb0f) about concurrency patterns in go -- those three I got from a quick google search. But if you have something specific in mind, I think I can address that too.

Looks like you want to crawl a website and get information from it's many pages concurrently, depositing that "information" into a common location (ie. a `slice`). The way to go here is to use a `chan`, chaonlinennel, which is a thread-safe (multiple threads can access it without fear) data-structure for channeling data from one thread/**goroutine** to another.

And of course the `go` keyword in Go is how to spawn a goroutine.

so for example, in a `func main()` thread:

```
// get a listOfWebpages
dataChannel := make(chan string)
for _, webpage := range listOfWebpages {
    go fetchDataFromWebpage(webpage, dataChannel)
}

// the dataChannel will be concurrently filled with the data you send to it
for x := range dataChannel {
    fmt.Println(x) // print the header or whatever you scraped from webpage
}
```

The goroutines will be functions which scrape websites and feed the `dataChannel` (you mentioned you know how to scrape websites already). Something like this:

```
func fetchDataFromWebpage(url string, c chan string) {
    data := scrapeWebsite(url)
    c <- data // send the data to thread safe channel
}
```

---

If your having trouble understanding how to use concurrent tools, such as channels, mutex locks, or `WaitGroup`s -- maybe you should start by trying to understand *why* concurrency can be problematic :)  I find the best illustration of that (*to me*) is the **Dining Philosophers Problem**, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem

> Five silent philosophers sit at a round table with bowls of spaghetti. Forks are placed between each pair of adjacent philosophers.
>
> Each philosopher must alternately think and eat. However, a philosopher can only eat spaghetti when they have both left and right forks. Each fork can be held by only one philosopher and so a philosopher can use the fork only if it is not being used by another philosopher. After an individual philosopher finishes eating, they need to put down both forks so that the forks become available to others. A philosopher can take the fork on their right or the one on their left as they become available, but cannot start eating before getting both forks.

If **practice** is what you're looking for, I recommend implementing this problem, so that it fails, and then trying to fix it using concurrent patterns :) -- there are other problems like this available to! And creating the problem is one step towards understanding how to solve it!

---

If you're having more trouble just understanding how to use Channels, aside from reading up on it, you can more simply think about channels as **queues** which can safely be accessed/modified from concurrent threads.